# Sum of outer products multiplied by a scalar in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, product, outer-join

I would like to vectorize the sum of products hereafter in order to speed up my Matlab code. Would it be possible?

```
for i=1:N
    A=A+hazard(i)*Z(i,:)'*Z(i,:);
end
```

where `hazard` is a vector (N x 1) and `Z` is a matrix (N x p).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With matrix multiplication only:

```
A = A + Z'*diag(hazard)*Z;
```

Note, however, that this requires more operations than [Divakar's `bsxfun` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376974/2586922), because `diag(hazard)` is an `N`x`N` matrix consisting mostly of zeros.

To save some time, you could define the inner matrix as `sparse` using [`spdiags`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html), so that multiplication can be optimized:

```
A = A + full(Z'*spdiags(hazard, 0, zeros(N))*Z);
```

#### Benchmarking

Timing code:

```
Z = rand(N,p);
hazard = rand(N,1);
timeit(@() Z'*diag(hazard)*Z)
timeit(@() full(Z'*spdiags(hazard, 0, zeros(N))*Z))
timeit(@() bsxfun(@times,Z,hazard)'*Z)
```

With `N = 1000; p = 300;`

```
ans =
    0.1423
ans =
    0.0441
ans =
    0.0325
```

With `N = 2000; p = 1000;`

```
ans =
    1.8889
ans =
    0.7110
ans =
    0.6600
```

With `N = 1000; p = 2000;`

```
ans =
    1.8159
ans =
    1.2471
ans =
    1.2264
```

It is seen that the `bsxfun`-based approach is consistently faster.

Comment: Works too! Add `A` maybe?

Comment: @Divakar Oops! Thanks. Corrected

Comment: Even better! I tried to use tic/toc and your method is 20% faster!

Comment: I'm glad it's fast for you. But for reliable timing you should use [`timeit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html). The `bsxfun`-based approach seems to be much faster on my computer. See my timing (I've edited my answer)

Comment: The intent is immediately clear with the purely matrix multiplication version, and that makes up for the minor speed difference IMO.

Comment: Hey @chappjc! Feel like answering some Matlab questions? Did you get tired of CUDA yet? :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Haha!  On the contrary, I've gone way down the rabbit hole with CUDA and C++.  The complexity of the two coming together is staggering.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and `matrix-multiplication` -

```
A =  bsxfun(@times,Z,hazard).'*Z + A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working perfectly, however, wouldn't be possible to vectorize it without using bsxfun (only with product of vectors/matrices)?

Comment: @AlessandroBeretta You can use repmat: `repmat(hazard,1,p).*Z`, but what's the reluctance with `bsxfun`?

Comment: No, it is just because it seems that the computing time does not decrease so much.... Anyway, thanks again for your answer!

Comment: I've added some benchmarking. The `bsxfun`-based approach is faster in all cases I've tested